# D3 How to place image next to horizontal line text

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, charts

I've created this D3 chart which displays the results sentiment value. However what I'm struggling to do is place an image next to the horizontal text. Using the JSFiddle as an example, lets say 'Result 2' is under 20%. There would be a sad face displayed to the right of the 'Result 2' text. Then if the value was higher than 20%... a happy face would be displayed instead. Is it possible to do this?

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/sopjzwst/3/

I've created the 2 different faces below the chart like so:

```
<img src="http://www.clipartkid.com/images/15/cartoons-cartoon-logos-cartoon-logo-design-gHlQ6b-clipart.jpg" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">

<img src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/Rid/8EG/Rid8EGpi9.png" alt="Sad face" height="42" width="42">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to define what's the image to append next to the bars:

```
svg.selectAll(".images")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("svg:image")
    .attr("x", function(d) {return x(d.value) + 4; } )
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.sentiment) + 10; })
    .attr("width", 42)
    .attr("height", 42)
    .attr("xlink:href", function(d){
            return d.value < 20 ? 
            "http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/Rid/8EG/Rid8EGpi9.png" :
            "http://www.clipartkid.com/images/15/cartoons-cartoon-logos-cartoon-logo-design-gHlQ6b-clipart.jpg"
    });
```

So, if `d.value` is less than 20 (true), it appends the first link, otherwise (false) it appends the second link.

Here is your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c3k8c3a4/

**EDIT** To display the images next to the *ticks*, not to the bars, change the `x` and `y` accordingly. This is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6uasj8hz/

Comment: Hello Gerardo, this is great but how would I place it next to the text? e.g. to the right of the 'Result 1' & 'Result 2' text and not in the chart itself

Comment: By "text" you mean "ticks". There is no space at the right of the ticks!

Comment: Next to the tick text? so it would go 'Result 1 *Image* *tick*'

Comment: Is this possible or not?