# Britechart - How to add icon images to chart y axis

Tags: javascript, vue.js, d3.js, charts

I'm using Vue with Britecharts, and I've created a horizontal bar chart, and then I want to add the avatar images to the y asis on the right side of the name label. I've done some research and I've found [D3 How to place image next to horizontal line text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40508241/d3-how-to-place-image-next-to-horizontal-line-text) and [this](https://jsfiddle.net/6uasj8hz/) has done exactly what I want to achieve but in D3.

I want to know how I can do the same in Britecharts. Below is my sample code.

**Codepen:** https://codepen.io/cooltaiwanesesam/pen/RwPYpbz

```
createHorizontalBarChart() {
    let barChart = new britecharts.bar(),
        margin = {left: 120, right: 20, top: 20, bottom: 30},
        barContainer = d3.select('.js-horizontal-bar-chart-container'),
        containerWidth = barContainer.node() ? barContainer.node().getBoundingClientRect().width : false;

    barChart
       .isHorizontal(true)
       .margin(margin)
       .width(containerWidth)
       .colorSchema(britecharts.colors.colorSchemas.britecharts)
       .valueLabel('percentage')
       .height(300);

    barContainer.datum(this.data.reverse()).call(barChart); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved. Sharing the code to help someone in need.

https://codepen.io/cooltaiwanesesam/pen/YzyXYWE

```
barChart
  .isHorizontal(true)
  .width(containerWidth)
  .height(300);

barContainer.datum(dataset).call(barChart);

d3.selectAll('.y-axis-group .tick')
  .each((d, i, list) => {        
    let img = barData.data.find((item) => item.name === d).img;

    d3.select(list[i])
      .append('image')
      .attr('x', -36)
      .attr('y', -22)
      .attr('width', 42)
      .attr('height', 42)
      .attr('xlink:href', img)
  });
```

Reference: https://github.com/eventbrite/britecharts/issues/798 Thanks to Marcos from Britecharts.

Comment: Great work there!!